# Почему при запуске конвертируемой программы на PyQt5 интерфейс не отображается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer

Программа до конвертации:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = uic.loadUi("ui.ui")
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Программа до конвертации]

---

Программа после конвертации:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Downloads/icon.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Russian, QtCore.QLocale.Russia))
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 381, 241))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 151, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.tab)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 16, 20))
        self.checkBox.setText("")
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 30, 61, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 161, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.tab)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 16, 20))
        self.checkBox_2.setText("")
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 171, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.tab)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 16, 20))
        self.checkBox_3.setText("")
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 150, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_11 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox_11.setObjectName("comboBox_11")
        self.comboBox_12 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 61, 22))
        self.comboBox_12.setObjectName("comboBox_12")
        self.comboBox_12.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_12.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_12.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_13 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 150, 61, 22))
        self.comboBox_13.setObjectName("comboBox_13")
        self.comboBox_13.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_13.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_13.addItem("")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setWhatsThis("")
        self.tab_2.setAccessibleName("")
        self.tab_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Программа после конвертации]

Конвертировал с помощью команды:

```
pyuic5 ui.ui -o main.py -x
```

в командной строке.

Comment: у вас какая-то битая конвертация, я не вижу `MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)` и видимо еще нет чего-то. Опубликуй те модуль `ui.ui` я гляну не него.

Comment: @S.Nick вот ссылка на файл ui.ui - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mk9S2KSJgucCXJ6TB7ekYWal2YM3zA-y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: да, `pyuic5` у меня выдает ошибку `Unknown Qt widget: QKeySequenceEdit`.  Виджет QKeySequenceEdit позволяет вводить QKeySequence. Этот класс был представлен в `Qt 5.2.` я эту версию еще не ставил.

Comment: @S.Nick у меня была та же ошибка, но файл все равно создался. Так как можно решить проблему? Обновить PyQt?

Comment: нет, файл получается обрезанный. добавьте в конце его `MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)` и увидите что получилось.

Comment: @S.Nick большое спасибо! Действительно, файл обрезан. Не подскажете из-за чего это могло произойти и как можно решить проблему? А то там нет половины программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо надо обновляться до версии 5.2. или попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("q1189493.ui", self)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Насколько я понял, вы используете нековертированный файл. А мне нужен ковертированный, для того чтобы в дальнейшем можно было прописать функционал графического интерфейса.

Способ встраивания вашей формы, которую вы подготовили в `Qt Designer`,
никак не влияет на дальнейшее написание вашей логики.

Я уже начал писать функционал, продолжайте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("q1189493.ui", self)

        # Тут вы пишите свой функционал ...
        # ...
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: print(f"Hello Button: {self.pushButton.text()}"))
        
        print(self.tabWidget.currentIndex())
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        
        self.comboBox_4.addItems(["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", ])
        
        # ...        
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]